White in Ubuntu 24 Garish
Im new to Ubuntu 24, its my first time that im adjusting the screen settings.
Nightmode is on, i tried to reduce screen brightness, but still the color white is so garish that it is hurting my eyes.
I tried things like xrndr but it doesnt help, does anyone knows hot to adjust the white tone, so that it isnt hurting my eyes?
White tones on libre office background or on websites are the issue.

Is it the Ubuntu desktop that is too bright or Libreoffice?  You've tagged your question with LO instead of Ubuntu.  If it's the GUI of ubuntu that is too light, which Ubuntu do you have?  (thinking Kubuntu, standard Ubuntu or perhaps XUbuntu).

I have Ubuntu 24.04, my eyes are hurting overall when the screen is white. Libre office was meant as a example, also right now on this homepage here it is difficult to stay concentrated.

Try the dark mode in setting, appearance. Unfortunately Libreoffice does not have a good dark mode or at least i did not find it. say if you need help with it.

Dark Mode is on, but still the White lighted surfaces, not just on libre, also on homepages are very cruel to my eyes. Is there a option to just change the contrast or specifially the white tone?
